# Printing Function Output in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to call two functions: `randompassword()` and `validPassword()`. The `randompassword()` function returns a random password to the user. The `validPassword()` function checks if the password is between 2 and 8 characters. I'm trying to create a third program that uses these two functions to generate a random password and then check if the password is valid. If it is not the program should run the program again and keep track how many times it has run.

```
#EX7P1
import string
import random
import sys

from ex7p1 import randompassword
from ex7p2 import validPassword
count = 0
def main():
    def randompassword():
        while password != 'true':
            count = count + 1
            print ("Hello!", password)
            print (count)


main()
```

These are the programs where the functions come from.

```
#EX7P1
import string
import random
import sys

def randompassword(): #function randompassword
    password = ''
    chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    size = random.randint(7, 10) #set range from 7 to 10
    for x in range(size):
        y = random.randint(33,126)
        password += chr(y)
    return password
```

These are two separate programs.

```
from ex7p1 import randompassword
password = randompassword()
def validPassword(password):
    if len(password) >= 8:
        print("true")
        return True
    print("false")
    return False
validPassword(password)
```

Comment: `If it is not the program should run the program again and keep track how many times it has run.` - how are you running the program again - is it triggered externally or you'll have a loop around `validPassword(password)` until you get a valid password? If former, you can store a counter on persistent storage (disk) - in a file/db, etc. If latter, you can create a global counter and increment the counter per iteration of the loop and print the value of this counter at the end.

Comment: It seems to me these could be combined into a single script file, and that may make your life a little easier

Comment: I'm trying to use separate programs. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy there are so many things I see wrong with this code...

1) These can easily be combined into a single script as shown below which makes the entire process less confusing.

2) You call the method `isalnum()` on a string and this returns either `True` or `False`...neither of these will ever be greater than or equal to 2.

3) Personally I like to use as few filler variables as possible. You can see that in `random_password()` you can take `y` out and just put the call to random in the next line

4) Why are you wasting time testing that your password is at least 8 characters??? Just change it to only generate passwords with an 8 character minimum as shown below.

5) There are unused imports and variables within your code. If you take these out (IDEs are your friend here) your code is much simpler and clear.

6) Your variable names should be more specific than just using `password` everywhere. This will make it easier to debug, as well as easier to read in several months/years when you try to go reuse the code.

7) I also tweaked the ascii codes generated to end at 122 to get rid of weird brackets that nobody wants in their passwords

```
import random


def random_password():
    generated_password = ''
    for x in range(random.randint(8, 13)):
        generated_password += chr(random.randint(33, 122))
    return generated_password


def validate_password(password_being_tested):
    if password_being_tested.isalnum():
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        password = random_password()
        test = validate_password(password)
        if test:
            break
    print("It took {} tries to make a password".format(count))
    print("Resulting password was: '{}'".format(password))
```

This script generated "7nLGxDFeqf" within 22 attempts on my machine and this seems like a reasonable and random password to me!